# how to copy a partition to a new drive and make it bigger

Tags: gparted, fdisk

I have a 500GB internal M.2 SSD , and bought a 2TB M.2 SSD with a case so I can load it exernally before replacing the internal drive.
The current setup is split into windows and linux partitions.

If I want to copy the windows and linux partitions, I need to specify the size of the partitions. But gparted only lets me specify the size in MB. What's the best way to copy the exact partition, then grow it?

As an experiment, I created a larger partition, then copied the existing linux one using dd, and it just displays 99% full. In other words, the 243GB paritition, now inside a 1.6TB partition, isn't properly using the new space. So clearly I need to copy, then resize.

Is there a way to do this with gparted? Do I have to use fdisk? Something else?

Comment: With gpt(GUID) partitions best not to use dd or any related programs. Gpt has GUID in primary partition, backup partition at end of drive & in partition. With Ubuntu typically easier & much better to just reinstall & restore from your backup. I can install & restore Ubuntu in about an hour. But last time I installed Windows (2006) it took most of a day. You might be able to clone Windows, move backup gpt partition table to end. Resize NTFS with Windows tools & then install Ubuntu, with desired partitions. If you have duplicate UUIDs you cannot reboot with both drives connected.

Comment: If you go into gparted from your USB installer, then find your 243GB partition. under the partition tab there is an option - *check*. Hit that and apply it. It would also be of help if you run *sudo parted -l* and post the output into your question, so that I can see the current layout of your partitions more clearly.

Comment: I dont know what happened to the answers that were here and downvoted, but copying the parititons in gparted is very good, and very fast. I am running popos which is very similar to ubuntu, but please tell me how you do a full backup and restore. Moreover, this does not solve the problem of doing it for windows.